# SET with SELECT in PostgreSQL not working

Tags: postgresql

I was trying to use **SET** with **SELECT** in PostgreSQL, but seems to be giving error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  "GET_READ_AUTHORITY_BITS_3" (RoleBO TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  DECLARE READ_AUTHORITY_BITS TEXT;
BEGIN
    SET READ_AUTHORITY_BITS = SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1);
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT" LINE 8:     SET
>   READ_AUTHORITY_BITS = SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing...
>                                         ^ SQL state: 42601 Character: 164

However **SET** and **SELECT** are separately working fine:

```
CREATE FUNCTION  "GET_READ_AUTHORITY_BITS_2" (RoleBO TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  DECLARE READ_AUTHORITY_BITS TEXT;
BEGIN
    SET READ_AUTHORITY_BITS = 'a';
    SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1);
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: You are not required to `SET` variables, you can set variables simply by naming them and using equals or colon equals operators if you are being strict `READ_AUTHORITY_BITS := 'a';`

Comment: @Lucaseven "READ_AUTHORITY_BITS = SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1);" works same way.

Comment: As does `SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1) INTO READ_AUTHORITY_BITS;` - there are many ways to skin a cat ;)

Answer (score 2):

`SET` is not for setting plpgsql function variables. It's for setting runtime configuration parameters. See the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-set.html).

If you want to assign the result of the `OVERLAY` function to the variable, you can accomplish that in multiple ways:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION  "GET_READ_AUTHORITY_BITS_3" (RoleBO TEXT)
RETURNS TEXT
AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  READ_AUTHORITY_BITS TEXT;
BEGIN
    -- 1.
    READ_AUTHORITY_BITS := OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1);
    -- 2.
    READ_AUTHORITY_BITS := (SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1));
    -- 3.
    SELECT OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1)
    INTO READ_AUTHORITY_BITS;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about PERFORM  SET_CONFIG ?

Comment: `SET_CONFIG` is also not for variables, it's for changing settings/runtime parameters. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html. `PERFORM` is just a way of doing a SELECT and discarding any result, rather than assigning the result to a variable or using it in some way. E.g. `PERFORM function()` will execute `function()` and discard any result it returns. If you did `SELECT function();` in plpgsql, it would complain that there's no destination for the result.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is possible to use SET in this way, possibly you could do this using EXECUTE:

```
EXECUTE format('SET READ_AUTHORITY_BITS = %L', OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1));
```

What I'm certain that you can do and get the same result is to use [set_config](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-SET):

```
PERFORM set_config('READ_AUTHORITY_BITS', OVERLAY('Apple' placing '' from 1 for 1), false);
```

By the way, your second example will most certainly throw error that there is no destination for your SELECT statement.

Well, I just read again your question and it seems like you did not want to use `SET setting = value`, but rather set variable of function. Will leave this just in case. Otherwise read Lucas comment.